# How to show a placeholder if video display failed

Tags: html, video, placeholder

I try to use a  tag to preview a picture of video, but if video format not support or url not found, it will not work, so could we use a placeholder picture to replace it? 
Please tell me some solution which works.

Thanks/Yang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wait for the video to be in a ready state, like:

```
var video = document.getElementById("videoId");

if ( video.readyState === 4 ) {
    // change the img tag z-index with a lower z-index than the video
}
```

This javascript says that when the video is fully loaded it replaces (actually, it goes on top) of an image that was covering it.
In HTML you put an img tag with a preview image to be shown until the video is loaded and you create a specific CSS for both img and video elements. Put the position to absolute or fixed or relative and apply a z-index of 2 for the img and 1 for the video element, making the image overlap on top of the video tag.
In Javascript when the video is fully loaded you can change the CSS of the img and video elements by exchanging their z-index from 2 to 1 and from 1 to 2, or by setting the img display property to none, that's to your liking.

Hope this helped!

Have a look at the documentation at mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are controlling it using javascript if yes use "if else" condition which as 2 placeholders(background image) one will be default one which means no preview and 2nd will be the videos placeholder.